# proof by induction for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

assume that P and Q are both nxn matrices and that P is invertible. Prove by induction on k that for all k>=1 (k greater than equal to 1) we have:
[image]

Please need help... i am stuck 
i figured out the base case for k = 1
and then after that i do not know how to proceed!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

\begin{align}
(PQP^{-1})^2= PQP^{-1}PQP^{-1} = PQIQP^{-1} = PQ^2P^{-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: how did you get I?

Comment: What is $P*P^{-1}$?